# How to determine the calling environment?

Tags: common-lisp

I am trying to shadow the mathematical operators in the CL package. Except for `*`, `/` and `+`, this works fine.  However the symbol-value of those symbols are set by the implementation to values that I use frequently at the REPL (the function is `interactive-eval` in SBCL).

Since they're set in the previous form evaluation, I can't get at them except through the symbol in the CL package, i.e. `cl:*`, after the form is evaluated.  I thought about making `*` a symbol macro that would dispatch on either my vectorised version of `*`, if in a function context, or return the value of `cl:*` otherwise.

However there doesn't seem to be an easy way to determine whether the symbol is being used as a function or value.

A stylised version of what I've got so far is:

```
(in-package :my-math-package)
(setf (fdefinition '+)   #'my-vectorised-version-of-+)`
```

Since my version of the `+` function is a superset of CL's, everything works fine, except for trying to use `*` at the REPL whilst in my package.  I could use `cl:*` and it works, but I'm trying to keep `cl:*` and `my-package:*` value slots synced.

One analogy for the symbol value might be:
`(setf (symbol-value '+)  #'cl:+)`

But that doesn't work for two reasons:

1. When compiling `cl:*` has no symbol value
2. Even if it did, it would not have the current value of the last evaluated form, it would have a 'snapshot' of the value of `cl:*` at the time.

So I need to dynamically keep `my-package:*` and `cl:*` to have the same symbol-value.

Anyone have any ideas?  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: can you give an example of what you are trying to do? it is a bit unclear to me what your problem is

Comment: `(define-symbol-macro my-plus cl:+)` together with 
```(defmacro my-plus (&rest whatever) `(my-vectorised-version-of-+ ,@whatever))```  seems to do what you want, right? (except that you would use your-package::+ as name, but this is irrelevant complication)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a classic edge-case of the package system in CL.  However for most purposes a symbol macro will do just what you want.

As an example, if I'm in a package where `*` is not `cl:*` then I can, for instance, say this:

```
(defun * (a b)
  (+ a b))

(define-symbol-macro * cl:*)
```

And now

```
> (* 1 2)
3

> *
3

> (funcall #'* 3 4)
7

> *
7
```

This is because symbol macros affect references to symbols *for value* not references for their function definition.

What you will lose is the ability to bind `*` and have that binding be special, because you can't declare symbol macros special.  So

```
> (funcall (let ((* 2))
             (lambda () *)))
2
```

for instance.  That's probably not a huge problem for `*`.

More significantly you will *also* lose any places where `*` is used just as a symbol.  For instance `(declare (type (array * (* *))) ...)` is no longer going to work, at all.  There is nothing you can do about this because these are simply uses of `*` as a symbol.  This is an inherent limitation of the package system.

---

As an aside: if you overload the operators of the field of numbers (so `*` and `+`) you probably want to think much harder about consistency than people usually do.  Or just give up on consistency, which is what people normally seem to do.  In particular `(+)` should return the zero of the field and `(*)` should return the 1 of it.  But ... which field?

Comment: Ugh.  I hadn't considered the case of type definitions and `*`.  I may just have to give up on the idea of syntactic consistency for vector mathematical operators and just name my functions something else.

Comment: `*` is almost the worst possible case here as it's used in so many places to mean so many things.